# SDK and AVD acting weird

Tags: android

I m having a weird problem with android sdk. I tried to install samsung_ace skin as instructed in samsung developer site, hence I just copied everything into the sdk add-ons folder but counldnt make any samsung ace emulator. Then I copied to the -android-sdk\platforms\android-8\skins folder , yet it says -Skin 'Galaxy_ace' does not exist,Missing skinpath in the AVD folder.

I also tried the same with Galaxy_S2 but that doesnt even show up in AVD manager's target/skin dropdown lsit.

Pls help. I just want to make An emulator for latest samsung TAB and Galaxy_S2.

Comment: try to restrat ADB using command line.

Comment: I did restart from DDMS view.